# XAMARIN Visual Studio 2017 - Android Emulator Black Screen

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, android-emulator, android-device-manager

I've recently run into the problem of the Android Emulator not deploying and showing a black screen instead.
I've been working on this problem for 24 hours now and I can't seem to fix it.

Even a blank Xamarin.Forms Project causes the Black Screen. I guess the path of the Android SDK might be wrong? (but I don't know how to fix it...)?

[image]

Comment: shutdown the emulator, run [Xamarin Device Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?tabs=windows&pivots=windows), edit the Emulator and change the [GPU emulation mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-properties?pivots=windows). Also try to update the GPU drivers in Windows.

Comment: I did and nothing works. Also the Base code of the project seems to produce errors... :-/

Comment: try to run the VM from device manager without VS and look if it boots. Also run SDK manager and update emulator to last version.

Comment: I had the same issue before. The way I fixed it is to create a new emulator and then run the project again.

Answer (score 1):

I got it resolved by running VS as administrator

Try it out.